# How can someone live in a Poste Restante?

Tags: meaning

In "The Worst Crime in the World" by G. K. Chesterton, Sir John was talking about his son who just left the country:

> “Some people I never heard of, called Grunov, have been pestering me, of all people, about his whereabouts,” said Sir John; “and I’ve just come in to send off a wire to tell them that, so far as I know, he’s **living in the Poste Restante**, Riga. Even that has been a nuisance. I came in yesterday to do it, but was five minutes too late for the post office. Are you staying long? I hope you will pay me another visit.”

How can someone live in a Poste Restante? Or he just meant live in **somewhere close to the Poste Restante**?

And why was this phrase **written with Capital letters?**

Comment: It is normal to spell 'Poste Restante' thus when addressing letters. In the US, 'General Delivery' is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that he does not know where his son is living. He is communicating with his son through Poste Restante, Riga, and knows nothing more. It is a joke.

It is in capitals as though it is the name of a hotel.

EDIT: Humorous speech and slang is very difficult for someone who has been taught English to get. Words are used in weird senses, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jeff :))

Answer (score 1):

It uses capital letters because it's being used as a proper name.

For instance, the Canadian post office is named *Canada Post*, with capitals.

According to the Wikipedia entry for [*poste restante*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante), several countries use it as a proper name, in addition to it just being a common noun:

> **Australia**
>   Poste Restante is a long-established service within Australia run by the national postal service, Australia Post, which allows one’s post to be sent to a city-centre holding place
>
> **Hong Kong**
>   In Hong Kong, Hongkong Post is responsible for handling the mail and mail can be sent to General Post Office only.
>
> At the address side, mark the mail with "Poste Restante" or "存局待領" in bold.

It would typically make more sense if the passage were *living **at** the Poste Restante, Riga* (using it as a kind of address). However, the odd preposition aside, it's still using the common noun as a proper name.

I'll note that Riga is the capital of Latvia.

---

It's also a kind of joke. It would be similar to the following:

> She spends so much time in her car, that she practically lives there. I might as well address letters to her at **Her Car** rather than her street address.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jason, that's really helpful :))